Series truncation
I am trying to evaluate an integral whose results contain several terms (in thousands) in the form $Ag+Bg^2 sin(gt) + Cg^3sin(gt)cos(gt)+...$with powers of g up to $g^8$. I would like to keep only the terms with $g^7$ and $g^8$, I tried using $Series[f[g],\{g,7,8\}]$ but this obviously messes with the Sin and Cos functions. Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Try: expression  /. g^n_ /; n < 7 -> 0

@DanielHuber Tried that for the simple case g+g^2+g^3 with the condition n<3 -> 0 and it gives g+g^3 instead of just g^3

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please present Mathematica code for a minimal example that can be copied, pasted and studied. This enables a focused interaction and a swift resolution. Thanks.

g does not match the pattern g^n, therefore you need to deal with it first. E.g.: g + g^2 + g^3  /. Plus[g, x__] :> Plus[x ] /. g^n_ /; n < 3 -> 0  this gives g^3

A useful trick is to match the things you don't want to change first e.g. {u:_Sin->Sin,g^n_/;n<7->0}

If you want to collect the coefficients of $g^n$ without expanding $\sin(g t)$ or $\cos(g t)$ in $g$, use Coefficient:
sample = 
 Sum[g^n*Total[Times @@@ Tuples[{Sin[g t], Cos[g t]}, n]], {n, 1, 8}]


Sum[Coefficient[sample, g, n]*g^n, {n, 7, 8}]


